# Magento 2: Create HTTP Paths to Frontend Assets via PHP Code

Tags: php, magento2, layout, javascript

In Magento 2, is it possible to generate an HTTP path to a module's front-end asset files (CSS, Javascript) using PHP?

i.e. I know it's possible to add code like the following to a layout handle XML file

```
<css src="foo/baz/bar.css"/>
<link src="Magento_Sales::js/bootstrap/order-create-index.js"/>
```

What I'm curious about is do these layout directives have direct PHP equivalents? If so, what are they.  If not, is there a reasonable technique for stabling reproducing their behavior via PHP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dug through the layout rendering code and found the answer to this one myself.  You can use a `Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository` to create asset objects, and then use the asset objects to get a URL.

That is, inject the `Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository` repository via automatic constructor dependency injection.

```
protected $assetRepository;
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepository
)
{
    $this->assetRepository = $assetRepository;
}
```

Use the asset repository to create an asset object

```
$asset = $this->assetRepository->createAsset('Vendor_Module::path/to/file.js')
```

and then use the asset object to get a URL

```
echo $asset->getUrl();
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is a direct PHP equivalent but you can do this in a block very easily

```
$this->getViewFileUrl() . '/' . $this->getModuleName()
```

This will give you a path like this

```
http://m2.dev/pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Package_Module
```

And of course you can leave out the module name if you want to get a theme resource.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is what you are looking for, but take a look on *Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config* public methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use also like this create the object of assets Repository

> $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
>
> $_assetRepo =
> $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository');
>
> echo $_assetRepo->getUrl("Globaliasoft_Banner::images/t1.png");

use your module name instead of Globaliasoft_Banner.